# Npm global install fails in VM because of missing "registry"?

Tags: npm, centos7

Im working on a VM with no free internet access in a coorperate setting. I can add a certain registry link so that using npm install works without any issues even with the restricted internet access. However when trying to do the same using npm **-g** install, it doesn't work and seemingly the issue is that it doesn't use the registry that I've added.

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.19.49-1560253987
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/bin/npm" "-g" "install" "ganache-cli"
npm ERR! node v6.16.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

Because this is also the message I used to receive when using npm install without having the registry added. Just that it only happens with global installs now.

I'd try and use it localy, but it seems like it needs to be installed globaly as, when I try to use the command line script by going into the node modules and executing the script, it gives me:
(truffle being the name of the script)

```
$ node truffle -version
/home/xxxxx/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:67600
  async execute() {
        ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:611:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:160:9)
[xxxxx.bin]$ node truffle --version
/home/xxxxx/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:67600
  async execute() {
        ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:611:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:160:9)
```

and using the other package I'm trying to install I get

```
$ node ganache-cli -g
/home/xxxxx/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:47
!function(){var r,a={};function i(){}function o(e){return e}function c(e){return!!e}function s(e){return!e}var f="object"==typeof self&&self.self===self&&self||"object"==typeof global&&global.global===global&&global||this;function d(e){return function(){if(null===e)throw new Error("Callback was already called.");e.apply(this,arguments),e=null}}function u(e){return function(){null!==e&&(e.apply(this,arguments),e=null)}}null!=f&&(r=f.async),a.noConflict=function(){return f.async=r,a};var l=Object.prototype.toString,b=Array.isArray||function(e){return"[object Array]"===l.call(e)};function p(e){return b(e)||"number"==typeof e.length&&e.length>=0&&e.length%1==0}function h(e,t){for(var r=-1,n=e.length;++r<n;)t(e[r],r,e)}function g(e,t){for(var r=-1,n=e.length,a=Array(n);++r<n;)a[r]=t(e[r],r,e);return a}function m(e){return g(Array(e),function(e,t){return t})}function v(e,t){for(var r=0;r<e.length;r++)if(e[r]===t)return r;return-1}var x=Objec

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/xxxxx/node_modules/ganache-cli/cli.js:12:13)
```

So that doesn't work either.

Is there some way to add the registry so that it uses it when I globally install something?

Is there something else that can be done to maybe make it work localy or is it maybe just some other problem that arises from the weird setting I'm working in?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is most likely that your vm clock is out of sync, so I would check that first. Here's what worked for me on centos:

First try:

```
yum install ntp
chkconfig ntpd on
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
service ntpd start
```

If that does not resolve your issue, you can (and I am warning you that this is not secure) try to alter the config for npm.

```
$ npm config set strict-ssl false
$ npm config set unsafe-perm true
$ npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```